# How to collect files on Windows machines with pywinrm?

Tags: python, windows, file, get, winrm

How to collect files on Windows machines?

Password rejected on pywinrm connection, but the password is correct and the connection port is listening

***Script:***

```
import winrm

s = winrm.Session('192.168.9.102', auth=('domain\username', 'password'))
r = s.run_cmd('ipconfig', ['/all'])

print(r.status_code)

print(r.std_out)
```

***Output:***

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/winrm/transport.py", line 329, in _send_message_request
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error:  for url: http://192.168.9.102:5985/wsman

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get.py", line 4, in <module>
    r = s.run_cmd('ipconfig', ['/all'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/winrm/__init__.py", line 39, in run_cmd
    shell_id = self.protocol.open_shell()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/winrm/protocol.py", line 166, in open_shell
    res = self.send_message(xmltodict.unparse(req))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/winrm/protocol.py", line 243, in send_message
    resp = self.transport.send_message(message)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/winrm/transport.py", line 323, in send_message
    response = self._send_message_request(prepared_request, message)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/winrm/transport.py", line 333, in _send_message_request
    raise InvalidCredentialsError("the specified credentials were rejected by the server")
winrm.exceptions.InvalidCredentialsError: the specified credentials were rejected by the server
```

***telnet 192.168.9.102 5985***

```
Trying 192.168.9.102...
Connected to 192.168.9.102.
Escape character is '^]'.
^CConnection closed by foreign host.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using another authentication transport like ntlm, according to your server configuration:

```py
winrm.Session('192.168.9.102', auth=('username@domain', 'password'), transport='ntlm')
```